# jsp prints java map in different ways with same code.

Tags: java, json, jsp, hashmap

I am working with jsp.
My jsp looks like ...

```
<%@page import="net.ion.ice.sp.shard.session.SessionManager"%>
<%@page import="net.ion.ice.sp.common.bean.user.Customer"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    Customer customer = SessionManager.getSessionUser(request.getParameter("session_id")) ;
    out.println(customer.getSessionDataMap()) ;
%>
```

quite simple. This code supposed to print java `Map<String, Object>` Object. 
Usually works fine, but sometimes it prints `JSON` way(meaning kolon connecting).

The result that I expected is

```
{default={CREATED={date=21, day=1, hours=11, minutes=10, month=2, nanos=0, seconds=13, time=1458526213000, timezoneOffset=-540, year=116}}}
```

And sometimes it returns

```
{default={CREATED={"date":21,"day":1,"hours":11,"minutes":10,"month":2,"nanos":0,"seconds":13,"time":1458526213000,"timezoneOffset":-540,"year":116}}}
```

As you can see some strings connected with `:`, but the other case it connects with `=`.

I do not know what makes the differs.
Thanks.

Comment: It call implicitly map.toString() mehod. If you have different output, it mean, you are using different classes (with different toString implementations).

Comment: This question is out of date and there is no-way to prove what was wrong with that code. So I think it is better to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Arrays#toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) with the entry set from your map to get a neatly printed map:

```
out.println(Arrays.toString(customer.getSessionDataMap().entrySet().toArray()));
```

For the following map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("one",   "first value");
map.put("two",   "second value");
map.put("three", "third value");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map.entrySet().toArray()));
```

This generated the following output:

```
[two=second value, one=first value, three=third value]
```

Note that if you want to maintain the insertion order of your keys, you can consider using `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question was why it prints in different format, not how to make it same. Thanks though. Now I am checking @degr 's reply.